# How to emphasize a word in xml-doc showing up in tool-tip?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper, xml-documentation

Is there a markup to emphasize (make bold, italic or whatever) a word in xml-doc? For example, in:

```
/// <summary>
/// Bla bla...
/// <para>
/// Important: take care of the wolf.
/// </para>
/// </summary>
```

I wan't the "Important" to be somhow emphasized (bold/italic/whaterver) when shown as a tool-tip when hovering over the member in Visual Studio (BTW, I'm using VS 2015 with R# 2016).

I've tried `<b>`, `<i>`, `<em>`, `<strong>` but non of the seem to work. I don't know if it's even possible at all.

Comment: On [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ast78ax.aspx) documentation page all recommended/supported tags are listed.  Non of them will be formatted in a tooltip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VS (as of 2015) tool tips do not support formatting.

But ReSharper's "Quick Documentation" feature (Ctrl+Shift+F1) is able to display the text with formatting.

[image: screen shot]

Comment: I wasn't even aware of this "Quick Doc" thingy. Just for the records: in R# keyboard scheme, it is available under (Ctrl+Q).